# Post Filtering by category

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I used this code for post filtering by post category. Categories are listed in a `ul` list. I want to pass that `li` value to my function. In this code only the first item value is passed.

```js
$(document).on("click", "#cats", function() {
  var selval = $("#cats").data('slug');
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/ajaxfiles/ajax-blog-cata.php",
    type: "POST",
    cache: 'false',
    data: {
      selval: selval
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $('#blog-cata').empty()
      $('#blog-cata').html(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You're only selecting one item, ie. `#cats'`. Assuming you've got the same `id` on multiple HTML elements, then that's the problem. Use classes instead and build an array of the values (assuming your PHP is configured to accept multiple values). If you need more specific help, we need to see the HTML and also the `ajax-blog-cata.php` file to understand how the data needs to be sent

Comment: Will be nice to see answer of this question! getting values in ul li without a form inputs by ajax. is it possible to do it with the code shown in question @RoryMcCrossan I will follow.

Comment: We don’t know what HTML structure this operates on to begin with, so this is practically unanswerable. Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue in cases like this.

Comment: @shilpa So do you want to pass multiple categories to ajax call for filtering ?